# When I get the ip address using the terminal, I get an ip address for a different website, how is this possible?

Tags: networking, terminal, dns, ip-address, ping

When I ping or traceroute the website I want to resolve, I get an ip address back, but when I put that into the browser, it leads to a different website. How is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IP address you are getting is for a SHARED HOSTING. In Shared Hosting multiple websites are hosted on same IP address. If you have dedicated hosting, you will get your website when you hit the IP address.

Answer (score 0):

The http request sent by your browser includes a `Host`  header that tells the server which website you are trying to reach. This is how multiple websites can be hosted with a single IP address.